# Find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from the left

Tags: calculus, limits

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
{0}  & \text{if $x<3$} \\x+1 & \text {if $3\le{x}\le4$}\\
5 &  \text{if $x>\ 4$} \\
\end{cases}$$

As it asks me to approach $3$ from the left I concluded that the answer would be $0$ as if it is $x<3$, $f(x)=0$. This seems too easy however so I would like to know if I did something wrong and what I can correct if I did do this question incorrectly.

Comment: No, that correct. $\lim_{x\to 3^-} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 3^-} 0 = 0$. (Also, why was this downvoted? The question is clear, and the OP did put some thought into this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct with your thought process.

$$lim_{x->3^{{-}}}f(x)=0$$

Remember that $x%$ approaches $3$ but never reaches it.

Thus $x$ is always in the domain of the section if $x < 3$.

> Note that you are only correct because **from the left**

Since the limit from the right is equal to $4$. The limit actually doesn't exist. But the 1 sided limits do.

Comment: If you write \lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x) = 0 when you are in math mode, you will obtain $\lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x) = 0$.   If you are in display math mode, you will obtain $$\lim_{x \to 3^-} f(x) = 0$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks. Ill keep that in my mind for the future